# Merging similar descriptions in bank statement output

Tags: r, quantmod

Here is a sample part of a bank statement:

```
Description<-c(
"EXXONMOBIL    46344172   "
"EXXONMOBIL    97142239   "
"EXXONMOBIL    97523322   "
"EXXONMOBIL    99123183   "
"JIMMY JOHNS - 1236    "
"JIMMY JOHNS - 2453   "
"JIMMY JOHNS # 95612   "
"KWIK FILL 212   "
"KWIK TRIP  24500001231   "
"KWIK TRIP  32100002342  "
"KWIK TRIP  67200003453   "
"MCDONALD'S F11123    "
"MCDONALD'S F11234    "
"MCDONALD'S F25345    "
"MCDONALD'S F5349   "
)

Debit<-as.numeric(c(
"25.98",
"24.54",
"29.59",
"31.85",
"7.61",
"17.82",
"10.58",
"26.5",
"22.48",
"146.62",
"52.51",
"2.57",
"7.77",
"9.59",
"11.85"
))

df<-data.frame(Description,Debit)
```

with the following output:

```
Description                 Debit
EXXONMOBIL    46946182      25.98
EXXONMOBIL    97302509      24.54
EXXONMOBIL    97585822      29.59
EXXONMOBIL    99374183      31.85
JIMMY JOHNS - 1476          7.61
JIMMY JOHNS - 2763          17.82
JIMMY JOHNS # 90012         10.58
KWIK FILL 228               26.5
KWIK TRIP  24500002451      22.48
KWIK TRIP  32100003210      146.62
KWIK TRIP  67200006726      52.51
MCDONALD'S F11780           2.57
MCDONALD'S F11883           7.77
MCDONALD'S F25398           9.59
MCDONALD'S F4789            11.85
```

I was wondernig how would it be possible to aggregate the results by Description so that the unique codes are removed and I get summarized amount of expenses by each company like Exxonmobil, Jimmy Johns, etc.. Not sure if the best way if to eliminate everything after a blank space, eliminate all the numeric characters, or (in my mind could be the best one) get rid of all numeric and special characters and keep only the letters?

In any way the desired output would be something like this:

```
Description     Debit
EXXONMOBIL      111.96
JIMMY JOHNS     36.01
KWIK FILL       26.5
KWIK TRIP       221.61
MCDONALD'S      31.78
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: check out [OpenRefine](http://openrefine.org)

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, while not ideal, it is a good option with its clustering function

Answer (score 1):

This would be fairly simple to do in REGEX.

E.g.

```
EXXONMOBIL.* (\d*.\d*)
```

[You can see it working here...](https://regex101.com/r/vPG1Qt/3/)

Once you have those values in a group you can use whatever language to sum together values or change out which root your searching for.

Comment: Thanks, you mean, I have to copy+paste my data on the website you provided? Or do I do it in R?